# CsvToBeanBuilder creating objects with null values

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, opencsv

I have a problem with `CsvToBeanBuilder` from `opencsv`. I have a class:

```
public class TransferNetworkRawData {

    @CsvBindByName
    private String jurisdiction;
    @CsvBindByName
    private String currency;
    @CsvBindByName
    private String transfernetwork;
    @CsvBindByName
    private String display;

    public TransferNetworkRawData() {
    }
    
    // getters and setters

}
```

And a service (FYI: `TransferNetworkDataFetcher` is just an interface with one method `getTransferNetworkData()`. I am creating this class in such manner, because I want the data to be loaded on application startup without having to read the file every time a request for this data comes.

```
@Component
public class CsvTransferNetworkDataFetcher implements TransferNetworkDataFetcher {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CsvTransferNetworkDataFetcher.class);
    private static final char SEPARATOR = ';';

    private List<TransferNetworkRawData> transferNetworkRawData = new ArrayList<>();

    public CsvTransferNetworkDataFetcher(ResourceLoader resourceLoader) {
        try {
            Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:" + "csv/transferNetworks.csv");
            CSVReader reader = new CSVReaderBuilder(new FileReader(resource.getFile())).build();
            transferNetworkRawData = new CsvToBeanBuilder(reader)
                    .withType(TransferNetworkRawData.class)
                    .withSeparator(SEPARATOR)
                    .build()
                    .parse();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            LOGGER.error("File not found! " + exception.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<TransferNetworkRawData> getTransferNetworkData() {
        return transferNetworkRawData;
    }

}
```

The CSV file looks like this (the file has 28 sets of data + header, so 28 objects in general)

```
jurisdiction;currency;transfernetwork;display
US;AAVE;ETHEREUM;TRUE
US;BAT;ETHEREUM;TRUE
EU;BCAP;ETHEREUM;TRUE
```

And a test:

```
@SpringBootTest
class CsvTransferNetworkDataFetcherTest {

    @Autowired
    private CsvTransferNetworkDataFetcher transferNetworkDataFetcher;

    @Test
    void shouldReturnTransferNetworkList() {
        List<TransferNetworkRawData> transferNetworkDataList = transferNetworkDataFetcher.getTransferNetworkData();
        System.out.println(transferNetworkDataList); // just for breakpoint
    }

}
```

Running this test shows some unexpected results, as `getTransferNetworkData()` is returning a list of 28 `TransferNetworkRawData` objects, but all the values (`jurisdiction`, `currency`, `transfernetwork` and `display`) in all those 28 objects are null, so it seems that the file is loaded correctly but the data isn't correctly read from it...

I have no idea what am I missing here...

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing with exactly the same issue in my source code. I just change this annotation `@CsvBindByName` for `@CsvBindByPosition(position = #)`

Your new model should be:

```
public class TransferNetworkRawData {
    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 0)
    private String jurisdiction;
    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 1)
    private String currency;
    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 2)
    private String transfernetwork;
    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 3)
    private String display;

    public TransferNetworkRawData() {
    }
    
    // getters and setters

}
```